# How to uppercase the first character of a word if it was not preceded or prefixed by a special character sequence?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, lookbehind

I am writing JavaScript code. The aim is to make every first character of a word uppercase after full-stop character (`Hello world. Hi`) while typing in `textarea`.

For that I'm using following code …

```
$('#div2').on('input', function (evt) {
    var re = /(^|[.!?]\s+)([a-z])/g;
    var box = evt.target;
    var stringStart = box.selectionStart;
    var stringEnd = box.selectionEnd; 
    var val = $(evt.target).val().replace(re, function (m, $1, $2) {
        return $1 + $2.toUpperCase()
    });

    $(evt.target).val(val);
    box.setSelectionRange(stringStart, stringEnd); 
});
```

Which works as expected.
But now i want it should skip some word like (U.S.A.). if one typed the the word U.S.A. in textare the first character of next word should not be uppercase.

```
E.g. 

    U.S.A. is the //Expected  
    U.S.A. Is the //what i am getting (wrong)
```

To achive this i wrote below code, which not working as expected.

```
var skipWordUpper = ['U.S.A.', 'Inc.'];
$('#div2').on('input', function (evt) {
    var re = /(^|[.!?]\s+)([a-z])/g;
    var box = evt.target;
    var stringStart = box.selectionStart;
    var stringEnd = box.selectionEnd;

    var str = $('#div2').val();
    var beforeSpace = str.split(" ").splice(-2) 
    var foundPresent = $.inArray(beforeSpace[0], skipWordUpper) > -1; 

    if (!foundPresent) {
        var val = $(evt.target).val().replace(re, function (m, $1, $2) {
            return $1 + $2.toUpperCase()
        });

        $(evt.target).val(val);
        box.setSelectionRange(stringStart, stringEnd);
    } 
});
```

Anybody will plz help to find out what mistake i am making and put me in proper way.
or any changes in regular exp. is required.
Apology for my hellybelly knowledge of JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Are you planning to use a whitelist of abbreviations, after which the capitalization of the first character shouldn't take place. Or do you assume any group of single characters followed by a dot character be like it

Comment: yes @yunzen , thats the ultimate goal.

Comment: Which one of the above?

Comment: Yeah im having group of some words followed by (.) for e.g.  BUS. , Co. etc. The words come after this should not be capitalize

Comment: So you are thinking of a whitelist?

Comment: Yeap.  @sbgib posted the answer, which achieve the goal.

Comment: Ok @PeterSeliger, then what u suggest for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a negative lookbehind to exclude those words in the regular expression:

```js
$('#div2').on('input', function(evt) {
  var re = /(?<!U.S.A|Inc)([.!?]\s+)([a-z])/g;
  var box = evt.target;
  var stringStart = box.selectionStart;
  var stringEnd = box.selectionEnd;

  var str = $('#div2').val();

  var val = $(evt.target).val().replace(re, function(m, $1, $2) {
    return $1 + $2.toUpperCase()
  });

  $(evt.target).val(val);
  box.setSelectionRange(stringStart, stringEnd);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="div2"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach to play with, based on something similar to e.g. ...

[`/(?<!\b(?:inc|pease|nope|U\.S\.A|u\.s\.w))([.?!]\s+)(\w)/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/zQ1gzo/1/)

Since the OP is looking for kind of a *whitelist-blacklist* support, a reliable approach has to sanitize such string-items. The regex has to be build dynamically from such a list. And therefore regex specific control characters need to be escaped before they are allowed to be part of the regex (search) pattern which then will be passed to the `RegExp` constructor.

Please also note that [*lookbehind assertions*](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) according to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#browser_compatibility) and to [**caniuse**](https://caniuse.com/?search=RegExp%20look) are not supported entirely amongst commonly used JS-engines, especially not with applying the full grammar of an regex to a lookbehind, like demonstrated with the following test case ...

```js
function toRegExpSearch(str) {
  return String(str)
    .replace((/[$^*+?!:=.|(){}[\]\\]/g), match => `\\${ match }`)
    .replace((/\s+/g), '\\s+');
}

const regXFirstWordCharAfterFullstop = (/([.?!]\s+)(\w)/g);
let regXFirstWordCharAfterFullstopException = null;

// please also have a look into ... [https://regex101.com/r/zQ1gzo/1/]

function updateFullstopExceptionRegX(evt) {
  const exceptionPattern = evt.currentTarget.value
    .trim()
    .split(/\s*,\s*|\s+/)
    .map(str => toRegExpSearch(str.replace((/\.$/g), '')))
    .join('|');

  regXFirstWordCharAfterFullstopException = (exceptionPattern !== '')
    ? RegExp(`(?<!\\b(?:${ exceptionPattern }))([.?!]\\s+)(\\w)`, 'gi')
    : null;

  document
    .querySelector('#regx')
    .textContent = String(regXFirstWordCharAfterFullstopException);

  sanitizeText({
    currentTarget: document.querySelector('#text')
  });
}

function sanitizeText(evt) {
  const textElm = evt.currentTarget;
  const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = textElm;

  textElm.value = (regXFirstWordCharAfterFullstopException === null)
    ? textElm.defaultValue
    : textElm.value
      .replace(
        regXFirstWordCharAfterFullstop,
        (_, $1, $2) => $1 + $2.toLowerCase()
      )
      .replace(
        regXFirstWordCharAfterFullstopException,
        (_, $1, $2) => $1 + $2.toUpperCase()
      );      
  textElm.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}

function init() {
  document
    .querySelector('#skiplist')
    .addEventListener('input', updateFullstopExceptionRegX);
  document
    .querySelector('#text')
    .addEventListener('input', sanitizeText);

  updateFullstopExceptionRegX({
    currentTarget: document.querySelector('#skiplist')
  });
  sanitizeText({
    currentTarget: document.querySelector('#text')
  });
}
init();
```

```css
input, textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
pre { margin: 3px 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<input id='skiplist' type="text" placeholder="... add word or abbreviation to skiplist ..." value="inc. pease, nope, U.S.A. u.s.w." />

<pre><code id="regx">(/(?:)/)</code></pre>

<textarea cols="40" rows="9" id="text" placeholder="...type or paste text freely...">
U.S.A. Is the country? i want to live in. if you please. yes. nope.
U.S.A. Is the country? i want to live inc. If you pease. Dope. yes.
U.S.A. Is the country? i want to live Inc. If you pease. Dope. yes.

u.s.w. And so on. a German abbreviation.
u.s.w. And so on. a German abbreviation.
</textarea>
```